# Programming Riddle: Counting down without subtracting

Tags: puzzle

Ok, goal by example : a command-line app that does this:

Countdown.exe 7

prints 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

No form of subtracting (including use of the minus sign) or string reverse what so ever is allowed.

waaaaay too easy apparently :-) An overview of the answers (the principles at least)

1. By adding and recursion
2. By using modulo
3. By pushing and popping, (maybe the most obvious?)
4. By using overflow
5. By using trial and error (maybe the least obvious?)

Comment: There is no need to post about someone voting to close. I doubt it will receive anymore votes.

Comment: The original text was: print 7 6 5 4 3 3 2 1, so there where two 3's ;-).

Comment: haha, that was meant to be of course, way too easy without the double 3 ;-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about adding and recursion?

```
public void Print(int i, int max) {
  if ( i < max ) { 
    Print(i+1, max);
  }
  Console.Write(i);
  Console.Write(" ");
}

public void Main(string[] args) {
  int max = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
  Print(1, max);
}
```

Comment: That would not work the way he has it as a parameter. But it could be modified.

Comment: @Daniel, see the updated sample

Comment: Yea. I guess you updated when i was typing that.

Comment: haha, exact the solution i came up with, I searched a bit longer I must admit.

Comment: Doest it make sense in CW to accept an answer?

Comment: @Peter, I think generally speaking most people eventually accept an answer for a community WIKI question.  It's by no means required though.

Comment: I meant : does rep still counts for the answerer? I accept an answer in any way, but will wait a bit , cause I don't want people to stop answering

Comment: @Peter, people get 0 rep for votes on a community WIKI answer (up or down). I think the person who's answer is accepted still gets the 15 points.

Comment: It's not for me to judge the solutions, just a bit of fun after all, so I accept whoever answered correctly first, and that was you.

Comment: Why do i always find it hard to think of recursion? :S

Comment: @Galilyou - the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763832/programming-riddle-counting-down-without-subtracting/763838#763838

Answer (score 46):

```
x = param;
while (x > 0) {
    print x;
    x = (x + param) mod (param + 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 for good use of modulo arithmetic.

Comment: Mod is division, which by definition is a form of subtraction. I would say that this doesn't count.

Comment: Modulus is not division. q(x) != r(x).

Math solved this problem.

Comment: clever subtraction! me like ^_^

Comment: @Scott — I would content that neither of those statements are true.  Modulus is typically *defined in terms of* division, but that doesn't *make it* division.  Ditto for division != subtraction.

Comment: @ScottWisniewski Interpret "form of subtracting" widely enough and every solution to this problem becomes invalid.  Even the solution I thought of involves subtraction, a massive string of ascii numbers that count down and a massive array of integers that index into it.  But subtraction is only involved when I'm typing out the data. :)  Then again, the requirements never specified that 8 and above would have to work.  Hmm... ;)

Answer (score 17):

Here's a method you missed, trial and error:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CountDown
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int currentNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        while (currentNum != 0)
        {
            System.out.print(currentNum + " ");
            int nextNum = 0;
            while (nextNum + 1 != currentNum) {
               nextNum = rand.nextInt(currentNum);
            }

          currentNum = nextNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got a chuckle out of that one...

Answer (score 15):

Push 1-7 onto a stack.  Pop stack one by one.  Print 7-1. :)

Comment: isnt't it considered array reversion??

Comment: There are many many ways to implement a stack.

Comment: The recursive solution just used the call stack as its stack; this is simply a not-necessarily-recursive interpretation.

Comment: The callstack is not a data structure.

Comment: @JP, so if you want to countdown from 100.000.000 you will create a stack of 100.000.000 elements and then pop the stack.....

Answer (score 13):

use 2's compliment, after all this is how a computer deals with negative numbers.

```
int Negate(int i)
{
   i = ~i;  // invert bits
   return i + 1; // and add 1
}

void Print(int max)
{
   for( int i = max; i != 0; i += Negate(1) )
   {
     printf("%d ", i);
   }
}
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2's_complement

Comment: Although isn't what you are doing essentially subtracting, since you're adding negative 1?

Comment: Well, the result is the same as if a subtraction had been done, but you'll see the example uses a +=, so it's a plus. But, the effect is the same as if a subtraction had been done. But, you could argue the effect of any other answer to this question is to have subtracted 1... so you could also say this answer is essentially the same as 'adding and recursion', which is the accepted answer. Or you could say it's essentially the same as prepending numbers into a string buffer or whatever. :)

Answer (score 11):

Prepend the numbers into a string buffer.

```
String out = "";
for (int i = 0; i < parm; i++)
{
   out = " " + (i+1) + out;
}
System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score 11):

c/c++, a bit of arithmetic overflow:

```
void Print(int max)
{
   for( int i = max; i > 0; i += 0xFFFFFFFF )
   {
      printf("%d ", i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Technically, adding a negative number is performing subtraction! d=

Comment: does not work when int==64bit

Comment: yes, true. i think my other answer with the 2's compliment was probably better. this is just an optimization of that that happens to require a 32 bit machine.

Comment: This is the solution I thought of first :)

Answer (score 10):

I note that nobody posted the stupidest possible answer, so I'll go ahead and share it:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  if ( ( argc < 1 ) || ( atoi(argv[1]) != 7 ) ) {
    printf("Not supported.\n");
  } else {
    printf("7 6 5 4 3 2 1\n");
  }
}
```

Don't hate me: See? I admitted it's stupid. :)

Answer (score 8):

use a rounding error:

```
void Decrement(int& i)
{
    double d = i * i;
    d = d / (((double)i)+0.000001); // d ends up being just smaller than i
    i = (int)d; // conversion back to an int rounds down.
}

void Print(int max)
{
   for( int i = max; i > 0; Decrement(i) )
   {
     printf("%d ", i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty nifty, Scott.  Way to exploit type-casting.

Answer (score 7):

This is not hard. Use the modulus operator.

```
for (int n = 7; n <= 49; n += 7) {
  print n mod 8;
}
```

Comment: upvoted for creativity, but please fix the infinite loop

Comment: The idea is good, but it doesn't work for any n other than 7.

Answer (score 7):

**Bitwise Arithmetic**

Constant space, with no additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, modulos or arithmetic negations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    for ( unsigned int value = atoi( argv[ 1 ] ); value; ) {
        std::cout << value << " ";
        for ( unsigned int place = 1; place; place <<= 1 )
            if ( value & place ) {
                value &= ~place;
                break;
            } else
                value |= place;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Btw you could get rid of that 'else'

Answer (score 3):

A python version:

```
import sys

items = list(xrange(1, int(sys.argv[1])+1))
for i in xrange(len(items)):
    print items.pop()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is cheating, right?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
def countdown(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print n
        n = n + (n + ~n)
```

And just for fun, its recursive brother:

```
def tune_up(n):
    print n
    if n == 0:
        return
    else:
        return tune_up(n + (n + ~n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with a file containing descending numbers from to the max you're interested in:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Then... this only works up to 9999

```
#!/bin/sh
MAX_NUM=9999
if [ ! -e descendingnumbers.txt ]; then
    seq -f%04.0f -s\  $MAX_NUM -1 1 > descendingnumbers.txt
fi
tail descendingnumbers.txt -c $[5 * $1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty version in Scala:

```
sealed abstract class Number
case class Elem(num: Number, value: Int) extends Number
case object Nil extends Number

var num: Number = Nil

for (i <- 1 until param)
  num = Elem(num, i)

while (num != null)
  num match {
    case Elem(n, v) => {
      System.out.print(v + " ")
      num = n
    }
    case Nil => {
      System.out.println("")
      num = null
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a minus sign!! .... I'm kidding :-P

Answer (score 1):

Increment a signed integer passed max_int and then "Add" it to the counter... or is this consider illegitimate subtraction?

Comment: It's another case of overflow, ok for me

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void print (int i)
    {
        Console.Out.Write("{0} ", i);
        int j = i;
        while (j > 1)
        {
            int k = 1;
            while (k+1 < j)
                k++;
            j = k;
            Console.Out.Write("{0} ", k );
        }
    }
```

Kinda nasty but it does the job

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CountUp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        while (n != 0)
        {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
            n = (int)(n + 0xffffffffL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks strangely familiar, i like it though! worthy of an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

```
// count up until found the number. the previous number counted is
// the decremented value wanted.
void Decrement(int& i)
{
  int theLastOneWas;
  for( int isThisIt = 0; isThisIt < i; ++isThisIt )
  {
    theLastOneWas = isThisIt;
  }
  i = theLastOneWas;
}

void Print(int max)
{
   for( int i = max; i > 0; Decrement(i) )
   {
     printf("%d ", i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are we golfing this?

```
import sys
for n in reversed(range(int(sys.argv[1]))):print n+1,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ARGV[0].to_i.downto(1) do |n|
  print "#{n} "
end
puts ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Haskell:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

func :: Integer -> [String]
func 0 = []
func n@(x+1) = show n:func x

main = putStrLn . unwords . func . read . head =<< getArgs
```

A 'feature' called n+k patterns allows this: pattern matching on the addition of two numbers. It is [generally not used](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/mail-www/haskell/msg01131.html). A more idiomatic way to do it is with this version of func:

```
func n = foldl (flip $ (:) . show) [] [1..n]
```

or, with one number per line:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Data.Traversable

main = foldrM (const . print) () . enumFromTo 1 . read . head =<< getArgs
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this count? Only uses an add instruction...

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   int x = 10;
   __asm mov eax,x;
   __asm mov ebx,0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (x > 0)
   {
      __asm add eax,ebx;
      __asm mov x,eax;
      __asm push eax;
      printf("%d ",x);
      __asm pop eax;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
$n = $ARGV[0];

while ($n > 0) {
  print "$n ";
  $n = int($n * ($n / ($n+1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subtraction is an illusion anyways

Comment: in that case, please subtract the balance of your bank account and give it to me. (assuming it's not already negative)

Answer (score 0):

I like Dylan Bennett's idea - simple, pragmatic and it adheres to the K.I.S.S principle, which IMHO is one of the most important concepts we should always try to keep in mind when we develop software. After all we write code primarily for other human beings to maintain it, and not for computers to read it. Dylan's solution in good old C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        int n;
        for (n = 7; n <= 49; n += 7) {
                printf("%d ", n % 8);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, using a rotating memory block (note, not something I'm proud of...):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_MAX 10

void rotate_array (int *array, int size) {
  int tmp = array[size - 1];
  memmove(array + 1, array, sizeof(int) * (size - 1));
  array[0] = tmp;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int idx, max, tmp_array[MAX_MAX];

  if (argc > 1) {
    max = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (max <= MAX_MAX) {
      /* load the array */
      for (idx = 0; idx < max; ++idx) {
        tmp_array[idx] = idx + 1;
      }
      /* rotate, print, lather, rinse, repeat... */
      for (idx = 0; idx < max; ++idx) {
        rotate_array(tmp_array, max);
        printf("%d ", tmp_array[0]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And a common lisp solution treating lists as ints:

```
(defun foo (max)
  (format t "~{~A~^ ~}~%"
          (maplist (lambda (x) (length x)) (make-list max))))
```

Making this into an executable is probably the hardest part and is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp

Counting down from 7 (with recursion, or like here, using `loop` and `downto`):

`(loop for n from 7 downto 1 do (print n))`

Alternatively, perhaps a more amusing soluting. Using complex numbers, we simply add i squared repeatedly:

```
(defun complex-decrement (n)
  "Decrements N by adding i squared."
  (+ n (expt (complex 0 1) 2)))

(loop for n = 7 then (complex-decrement n)
      while (> n 0) do (print n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like recursive

```
function printCountDown(int x, int y) {
  if ( y != x ) printCountDown(x, y++);
  print y + " ";
}
```

You can also use multiplication

```
function printNto1(int x) {
  for(int y=x*(MAXINT*2+1);y<=(MAXINT*2+1);y++) {
    print (y*(MAXINT*2+1)) + " ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative perl version could be:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print reverse join(" ",1 .. $ARGV[0]) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

C:

```
char buf[2][50];
int buf_no, i;

buf_no = buf[0][0] = buf[1][0] = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i, buf_no = !buf_no) 
    sprintf(buf[buf_no], "%d %s", i, buf[!buf_no]);

printf(buf[!buf_no]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
<?=implode(",", array_reverse( range(1, $_GET['limit']) ) )?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And now for abusing string functions!

```
using System;
public class Countdown {
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        int start = 10;
        string buffer;
        if (args.Length > 0) start = int.Parse(args[0]);
        buffer = "".PadRight(start, 'z');
        while (buffer.Length > 0){
            Console.Write(buffer.Length.ToString() + " ");
            buffer = buffer.Substring(1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Scala implementation

```
class Countdown(countFrom: Int, countTo: Int) {
  def printListInReverse() = {
    val standardCount = for (i <- countFrom to countTo) yield i
    println(standardCount.reverse.mkString(" "))
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about adding negative 1?

Comment: no, that's subtracting by one by very definition. To make it more clear :don't use the minus sign

Answer (score -1):

Count up from -7 & don't print the minus sign:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
for i in range(-7, 0): print str(i)[1],
```

Comment: The problem called for no form of subtraction, including using a minus sign.  You didn't meet that requirement.

Comment: Yeah but he's a cheeky bastard!

Answer (score -1):

Output to temporary string, then reverse it, then reverse individual numbers:

```
string ret;
for(int i=0;i<atoi(argv[1]);i++)
  ret += " " + itoa(i);

for(int i=0;i<ret.length()/2;i++)
   exchange(ret[i],ret[ret.length()-i-1]);

for(const char* t=&ret[0];t&&strchr(t,' ');t=strchr(t,' '))
for(int i=0;i<(strchr(t,' ')-t)/2;i++)
   exchange(t[i],t[strchr(t,' ')-t-1]);

printf(ret.c_str());
```